# Pointers acting weird

Tags: c++

Note that we had this as school practise problem, not sure if I will ever use it in real life.

So this works :

```
int main(){

  int *** niz[6];

  **niz[0] = new int(6);

  cout << ***niz[0];

}
```

but this doesen't :

```
int main(){

  int **** niz[6];

  ***niz[0] = new int(6);

  cout << ****niz[0];

}
```

it results in segmen. fault. Why is that, stars match ?

But

Comment: Why does `int *ptr; *ptr = 5;` result in a segmentation fault, even though the stars match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont insert valid addresses into your array so both are Undefined Behaviour, ie. under gcc run fine, but under clang caused segfault. To make it run you need to insert real addresses:

```
int main(){
  int * niz1 = new int(6);
  int ** niz2 = &niz1;
  int *** niz3 = &niz2 ;

  int **** niz[6];

  niz[0] = &niz3;

  std::cout << ****niz[0];
}
```

whooah, its the first time I coded level four pointers

Comment: well compiler tricked me into believing that it could work that way. thanks for clearing it up for me

Comment: @nhrnjic6 Not everything that compiles works, and making sure your program works isn't the compiler's job.

Comment: @nhrnjic6: The compiler didn't trick you. It never made any promises that it would prove the correctness of your program. You were just making blind assumptions and then started basing your world view on those assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

Mind that `niz` is completely **uninitialized**.

Let's take `*niz`, for example. It dereferences the address at `niz[0]`. `niz[0]` is uninitialized however, so it's undefined behavior.
You don't need to think through anything beyond that to figure out why it's giving a segmentation fault.

Both programs yield undefined behavior. An unlucky coincidence the first one runs fine.